# I am declaring default server side encryption(SSE-KMS) through terraform, so is their a way to enable and disable encryption through terraform?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

Is their a way to enable and disable server side encryption(SSE-KMS) using terraform, by just passing variables or something?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [it lacks evidence of research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).